# Should a variable that is modified by all functions in a program be global?

Tags: c, pointers, extern

I feel like in general, people feel uncomfortable using global variables. I have read and heard that the smaller the scope of a variable, the better. The main reason was to prevent unexpected modifications of the variable.

If a program uses the same variable in each of its functions, there shouldn't be any unexpected modifications related to the scope. In this context, could we make this variable global, instead of dragging a pointer all around the program?

Comment: That's what the global variables are for.

Comment: It's absolutely fine, (until you decide to multithread any part of it).

Comment: Depends. It may be perfectly reasonable now. But be warned that if you have one too many globals and your program grows in complexity, it may become very hard to root them out eventually. That's why people often say they are best avoided.

Comment: you may also create private global scope in your c file with using static keyword. static keyword provide global usage in your c file while your variable not seen out of your file scope